# Insertion sort Pseudo code vs implementation?

Tags: sorting, python

So I'm trying to implement an `insertion sort` algorithms based on [page 18 Cormen psuedocode](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf#page=39) but I'm confused by `for j = 2 to A:length`. Specifically, what does the `j=2` mean? I'm implementing it using the below python code and it only works when the range is the entire length of the array:

```python
def insertion_sort(arr):
    # length of array
    n = len(arr)

    # traverse through array
    for i in range(n):
        key = arr[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key < arr[j]:
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1
        arr[j + 1] = key
```

Could someone explain?

Comment: Most of us probably don't have a copy of Cormen page 18, and it's probably not possible to answer this question without context from what is in the book.  Can you transcribe the pseudocode you are looking at?  I don't know how to answer "what does j=2 mean?" -- it is presumably a line of code that you are supposed to implement.  I don't know how to answer questions about the meaning of a line of code; it just is whatever it is.

Comment: One thing to find out is whether "CLRS" assume `A` one- or zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two points might clear your confusion.

1. The pseudocode in the book is following $1$ based indexing. Your code is following $0$ based indexing.
2. Your code is technically doing nothing in the first iteration of the while loop. In the first iteration $i = 0$, therefore $j = -1$. Since $j<0$, the inside while loop is not executed. And it keeps $A[0] = key$ to its original value. Effectively, your code starts executing from $i = 1$, which is equivalent to $j = 2$ in CLRS implementation.